# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not calling in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5, xcode12

I already worked on *UIImagePickerController*. This code was already works fine in **Xcode 11.3**. But when I run on Xcode 12 Image picker *delegate* is not calling in **Xcode12**.

```
/// Picked Image
struct PickedImage {
    var image: UIImage?
    var api: String?
}

/// Image picker
class ImagePicker: NSObject {
        
    typealias ImagePickerHandler = ((_ selected: PickedImage) -> ())
    
    private weak var presentationController: UIViewController?
    
    let pickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    var apiKey: String?
    
    private var handler: ImagePickerHandler? = nil
    
    private func action(for type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, title: String) -> UIAlertAction? {
        
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(type) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default) { (action) in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                self.pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
                self.pickerController.sourceType = type
                self.pickerController.delegate = self
                
                self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true, completion: {
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Present source view
    /// - Parameter sourceView: view
    func present(presentationController: UIViewController, completed: ImagePickerHandler? = nil) {
        
        self.handler = completed
        
        self.presentationController = presentationController
        // self.delegate = delegate
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
        if let action = self.action(for: .camera, title: "Take photo") {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        if let action = self.action(for: .savedPhotosAlbum, title: "Camera roll") {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        if let action = self.action(for: .photoLibrary, title: "Photo library") {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        
        //            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        //                alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sourceView
        //                alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
        //                alertController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down, .up]
        //            }
        self.presentationController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }
    
    private func pickerController(didSelect image: UIImage?, imageURL: URL?) {
        
        pickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        // self.delegate?.imagePicker(picker: self, didSelected: image, apikey: apiKey)
        
        handler?(PickedImage(image: image, api: apiKey))
    }
}

/// ImagePicker controller delegate
extension ImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        
        self.pickerController(didSelect: nil, imageURL: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        self.pickerController(didSelect: info[.originalImage] as? UIImage, imageURL: info[.imageURL] as? URL)
    }
}
```

When I check delegate is applied or not using breakpoint. like in console means

```
po imagepicker.delegate
```

there after image picker delegate was working fine. But when I remove breakpoint its delegate is not calling.

I don't know what is the reason. Why its not working. May I know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you're not retaining your picker controller in a variable. As soon as your function finishes, it gets deallocated.

For example I have something like this:

```
class MyClass: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
   let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
}

func pickImageFromGallery() {
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

... and the delegate methods as well
```

Comment: perhaps edit your question and post the whole function and any related code, rather than a few separated lines. it should help.

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason to not put `pickerController.delegate = self` before `self.presentationController?.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: {})'`?

if no, maybe you can put `pickerController.delegate = self` before that, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a silly mistake. just change a few lines of code and then you are good to go.

just follow my Steps

=> Here ProfileViewController is my UIViewController where I am going to pick Image from Gallery and Set image to UIImageView. You have to use your UIViewController where you want to Pick an Image.

```
ProfileViewController: UIViewController{

let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()

viewDidLoad(){

}

@IBAction func pickImageAction(sender: UIButton){
 self.openImagePicker()
}

func openImagePicker()
{
pickerController.delegate = self
pickerController.allowsEditing = true
pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary // Pick image from PhotoLibrary  
//pickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum // Pick Saved Images
//pickerController.sourceType = .camera  // Click Image using Camera
self.present(pickerController, animated: true)
} //End of setupImagePicker


} // End of ProfileViewController
```

```
// MARK:- Delegate method for UIImagePicker
extension ProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }

// image is your image which you picked from Image Gallery or using Camera.
// you can set this image directly to your UIImageView.
// self.yourImageView.image = image

// or you can compress this image, converting to JPG image type.
// compressionQuality will reduce your image quality and Image Size.
    if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
      // you can use this compressed image.
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true)


}//  End of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo 


} // End of Extension
```

Answer (score 0):

You code was always wrong; it's just lucky if it ever worked:

```
  let pickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
  pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
  pickerController.sourceType = "Photo library"
  self.presentationController?.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: {
      pickerController.delegate = self
  })
```

Change to:

```
  let pickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
  pickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
  pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
  pickerController.delegate = self
  self.present(pickerController, animated: true)
```